# Buf: Import protocol buffers from another project

Tags: protocol-buffers, protoc, buf

I am using [buf](https://docs.buf.build/generate/usage) CLI to generate protos for Go via command `buf generate`.

I am able to generate protos successfully if any imports are defined in the same directory.

However, I could not import protos from another repository or even the same repository but different folder.

Here is how I tried to import `error.proto` from the same repository to `service.proto`.
It might be a different repository as well.

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

option go_package = "github.com/organization/repository/service/proto/gen/service/v1;servicev1";

package service.v1;

import "github.com/organization/repository/common/proto/def/error/v1/error.proto";
```

This file relies inside directory:

```
service/proto/def/service/v1/service.proto
```

and my `buf.gen.yaml` look like

```yaml
version: v1
plugins:
  - name: go
    out: ../../
    opt: module=github.com/organization/repository/service
  - name: go-grpc
    out: ../../
    opt: require_unimplemented_servers=false,module=github.com/organization/repository/service
```

I call `buf generate` in directory:

```
cd service/proto/def
buf generate
```

Error message is:

```
common/proto/def/error/v1/error.proto: does not exist
```

Is it possible to import that error.proto? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

With the protobuf `import` statement, there is an expectation that it relates to some actual filesystem path.. be it relative to the directory including the file with the import statement, or relative to some path specified via `-I` / `--proto_path`.

So the import

```
import "github.com/organization/repository/common/proto/def/error/v1/error.proto";
```

..would imply that that path exists somewhere, but it clearly doesn't. Within a single repository, one simple option is to have your `buf.work.yaml` and `buf.gen.yaml` in the root, and use imports relative to the root of the repository. For imports relating to other repositories, you may find Buf Schema Registry (BSR) is helpful here.

See also [Import protobuf file from GitHub repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74259855/import-protobuf-file-from-github-repository)

Comment: it worked, thanks but how can I ignore `vendor` directory?

Comment: I think unfortunately you have to use `buf generate --exclude-path=vendor` - see https://github.com/bufbuild/buf/issues/224